# Windows Server 2012 Foundation. Mouse stops working during RDP session

Tags: windows-server-2012, rdp, mouse

We have a strange problem under Windows Server 2012 foundation. All latest Auto updates are installed.

We start an RDP session, and everything works ok. The problem is that in the moment we open certain apps, mouse stops working, and only keyboard works.

So far, I've detected this happens when I open SQL Server Management Studio, and also happens when I open Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2013 client.

We are still able to see the cursor, but mouse clicks don't work. At this moment we can only use keyboard to do anything in the session.

Comment: You can try updating Hyper-V Integration Services in the virtual machine. To update the Integration services, you will need Hyper-V server Manager access.

Comment: This is not a virtual machine environment..HyperV is not installed in this server.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, when starting Dynamics NAV 2103. Problem was with Process Microsoft Tablet PC Components (32 bit) WISPTIS.EXE. When i killed this process started with my user, mouse started working again.

What probably happened here is that when u start some applications OS switches to tablet mode, and turns off mouse input and probably expects touch inputs, which it don't get so u have just feeling that mouse is not working...

We are still looking how to disable it... there are lot of solutions, we jut wanna find the best one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Win2012 R2 server, mouse would move, but no clicks would register.  I signed out and signed in again and the problem went away.  To sign out without a mouse, hit the window key (or in RDS send the Start command) and tab until the userid is highlighted.  Press space bar and arrow-down until "sign out" is highlighted.  Then press Enter.  Sign in again and the mouse works.